# to do or to conduct the digital marketing?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

In English, do we say to do or to conduct the digital marketing?

The original text is as follows:

> With the popularity of digital life, at this time, not only big advertisers but also millions of small and medium enterprises in China cannot ignore the importance of digital marketing; however, they are facing a shortage of talents, who can help enterprises **to do the digital marketing**. David, one of the leading sales marketing dealers in China, said, “ The talents we need the most at this moment are digital marketing consolers who have practical experience and are able to communicate with the enterprises.”

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a matter of style rather than simply a question of grammar.

We would say

> do the cooking
>
> do the cleaning

but somehow

> do the digital marketing

sounds a little banal. I agree that

> conduct the digital marketing

does seem better. This may be because digital marketing is not a simple, one-off task; it tends to be an ongoing activity, often with interactive elements involving social media.